# How to add favorite_List Activity using sharedpreference to ListView activity in android

Tags: java, android, xml

The is the type of listView i'm trying to create: When a user clicks on list, it takes the user to newActivity where the user will find the full content of the listView. And on longPressed adds the list item to favoritesList.

After following a tutorial about how to add favoritesActivity in a Listview with BaseAdapter, i got an error. That is; my app forces-close on launch. I know i have missed some lines or may have unknowingly added non-formatted objects that could lead to app crash. I have included the logCat report for you to help me fix the problem that causes crash. I'm new to programming and i want to learn using this program. I am a student, please i need your help so as to complete my project.

All my trials and error are included in the codes shown. Please i want you to help me with a fix solution.Thanks

This is the MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
    private String TAG = "MainActivity ----- ; " ;
    // Store instance variables

    private int page;
    private ConsentForm form;

    ListView listView;
    ListViewAdapter adapter;
    String[] title;
    String[] description;
    int[] icon;
    ArrayList<Model> arrayList = new ArrayList<Model>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setTitle("Redeemed Songs");

        title = new String[]{"This is the lyrics content example of the song1, This is the lyrics content example of the song2, This is the lyrics content example of the song3, This is the lyrics content example of the song4, This is the lyrics content example of the song5",};

        description = new String[]{"MORNING", "MORNING", "MORNING", "MORNING", "MORNING", "MORNING",};

        icon = new int[]{ R.drawable.song, R.drawable.song, R.drawable.song, R.drawable.song,R.drawable.song,R.drawable.song,};

        listView = findViewById(R.id.list);

        for (int i =0; i<title.length; i++){
            Model model =new Model(title[i], description[i], icon[i]);
            //bind all strings in an array
            arrayList.add(model);
        }

        //pass result to listview class
        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, arrayList);

        //bind the adapter to the listview class
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

        MenuItem myActionMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView)myActionMenuItem.getActionView();
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(s)){
                    adapter.filter("");
                    listView.clearTextFilter();
                }
                else {
                    adapter.filter(s);
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id==R.id.action_settings){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class));
            return true;
            //do your funtionality here

        }
        else if (id==R.id.action_howtouse){
                Toast.makeText(this, "manual", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Main3Activity.class));
            return true;
                //do your funtionality here


        }
        else if (id==R.id.action_developers){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Favorites", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Main4Activity.class));
            return true;
            //do your funtionality here

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is the Model.java Class

```
public class Model {

    String title;
    String desc;
    int icon;
    int fav_icon;

    public Model(int fav_icon) {
        this.fav_icon = fav_icon;
    }

    public int getFav_icon() {
        return fav_icon;
    }

    //constructor

    public Model(String title, String desc, int icon) {
        this.title = title;
        this.desc = desc;
        this.icon = icon;
    }


    //getters


    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public int getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }

}
```

This is the row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mainIcon"
        android:src="@drawable/song"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mainTitle"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#740303"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mainDesc"
            android:text="Description"
            android:textColor="#262626"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/list_fav_icon"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_favorite_active"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the ListViewAdapter.java class

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    //Variables
    Context mContext;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    List<Model> modellist;
    ArrayList<Model> arrayList;
       private Model model;
       CheckBox checkFavoriteItem;
       SharedPreference sharedPreference;

    //Constructor
    public ListViewAdapter(Context context, List<Model> modellist) {
        mContext = context;
        this.modellist = modellist;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        this.arrayList = new ArrayList<Model>();
        this.arrayList.addAll(modellist);

    }

    public class ViewHolder{
        TextView mTitleTv, mDescTv;
        ImageView mIconTv, favIcon;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return modellist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return modellist.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (view==null){
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);

            //locate the views in row.xml
            holder.mTitleTv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mainTitle);
            holder.mDescTv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mainDesc);
            holder.mIconTv = view.findViewById(R.id.mainIcon);
            holder.favIcon = view.findViewById(R.id.list_fav_icon);

            view.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
        }

               //set the result into textview
        Model model = (Model) getItem(i);
        holder.mTitleTv.setText(modellist.get(i).getTitle());
        holder.mDescTv.setText(modellist.get(i).getDesc());
        //Set the result in imagview
        holder.mIconTv.setImageResource(modellist.get(i).getIcon());
        holder.favIcon.setImageResource(modellist.get(i).getFav_icon());

        if (checkFavoriteItem(model)) {
            holder.favIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_active);
            holder.favIcon.setTag("yes");
        } else {
            holder.favIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_default);
            holder.favIcon.setTag("no");
        }

        //listview item clicks
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //code later
                if (modellist.get(i).getTitle().equals("This is the lyrics content example of the song1")){
                    //start NewActivity with title for actionbar and text for textview
                    Intent intent =  new Intent(mContext, NewActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("actionBarTitle", "Song 001");
                    intent.putExtra("contentTv", "This is the lyrics content example of the song2");
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                }
                if (modellist.get(i).getTitle().equals("This is the lyrics content example of the song1")){
                    //start NewActivity with title for actionbar and text for textview
                    Intent intent =  new Intent(mContext, NewActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("actionBarTitle", "Song 002");
                    intent.putExtra("contentTv", "This is the lyrics content example of the song2");
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                }
                if (modellist.get(i).getTitle().equals("This is the lyrics content example of the song3")){
                    //start NewActivity with title for actionbar and text for textview
                    Intent intent =  new Intent(mContext, NewActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("actionBarTitle", "Song 003");
                    intent.putExtra("contentTv", "This is the lyrics content example of the song3");
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                }
                if (modellist.get(i).getTitle().equals("This is the lyrics content example of the song4")){
                    //start NewActivity with title for actionbar and text for textview
                    Intent intent =  new Intent(mContext, NewActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("actionBarTitle", "Song 004");
                    intent.putExtra("contentTv", "This is the lyrics content example of the song4");
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                }
                if (modellist.get(i).getTitle().equals("This is the lyrics content example of the song5")){
                    //start NewActivity with title for actionbar and text for textview
                    Intent intent =  new Intent(mContext, NewActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("actionBarTitle", "Song 005");
                    intent.putExtra("contentTv", "This is the lyrics content example of the song5");
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                }

            }
        });

        final ImageView favoritesbutton = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_fav_icon);
        favoritesbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String tag = favoritesbutton.getTag().toString();

                if (tag.equalsIgnoreCase("no")){
                    sharedPreference.addFavorite(mContext, modellist.get(i));
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, R.string.add_favr, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    favoritesbutton.setTag("yes");
                    favoritesbutton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_active);
                }else{
                    sharedPreference.removeFavorite(mContext, modellist.get(i));
                    favoritesbutton.setTag("no");
                    favoritesbutton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_default);
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, R.string.favorites_remove_msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });


        return view;
    }

    //Checks whether a particular product exists in SharedPreferences*/
    public boolean checkFavoriteItem(Model checkCode) {
        boolean check = false;
        List<Model> favorites = sharedPreference.getFavorites(mContext);
        if (favorites != null) {
            for (Model model : favorites) {
                if (model.equals(checkCode)) {
                    check = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return  check;
    }

    public void add(Model model) {
        modellist.add(model);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    public void remove(Model model) {
        modellist.remove(model);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    //filter
    public void filter(String charText){
        charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        modellist.clear();
        if (charText.length()==0){
            modellist.addAll(arrayList);
        }
        else {
            for (Model model : arrayList){
                if (model.getTitle().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText)){
                    modellist.add(model);
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

 }
```

This is SharedPreference.java Class for stored value

```
public class SharedPreference {

    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "REDEEMED_APP";
    public static final String FAVORITES = "code_Favorite";

    public SharedPreference() {
        super();
    }

    // This four methods are used for maintaining favorites.
    public void saveFavorites(Context context, List<Model> favorites) {
        SharedPreferences settings;
        Editor editor;

        settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = settings.edit();

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String jsonFavorites = gson.toJson(favorites);

        editor.putString(FAVORITES, jsonFavorites);

        editor.commit();
    }

    public void addFavorite(Context context, Model product) {
        List<Model> favorites = getFavorites(context);
        if (favorites == null)
            favorites = new ArrayList<Model>();
        favorites.add(product);
        saveFavorites(context, favorites);
    }

    public void removeFavorite(Context context, Model model) {
        ArrayList<Model> favorites = getFavorites(context);
        if (favorites != null) {
            favorites.remove(model);
            saveFavorites(context, favorites);
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<Model> getFavorites(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences settings;
        List<Model> favorites;

        settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        if (settings.contains(FAVORITES)) {
            String jsonFavorites = settings.getString(FAVORITES, null);
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Model[] favoriteItems = gson.fromJson(jsonFavorites,
                    Model[].class);

            favorites = Arrays.asList(favoriteItems);
            favorites = new ArrayList<Model>(favorites);
        } else
            return null;

        return (ArrayList<Model>) favorites;
    }
}
```

This is MyFavoriteActivity.java class which is meant to shaow stored list

```
public class MyFavoriteActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    SharedPreference sharedPreference;
    List<Model> favorites;

    FavouritesAdapter favouritesAdapter;
    Context context = this.context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_favorite);

        sharedPreference = new SharedPreference();
        favorites = sharedPreference.getFavorites(MyFavoriteActivity.this);

        if (favorites == null){
            Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MyFavoriteActivity.this);
            dialog.setTitle(R.string.no_favorites_items);
            dialog.show();
        }else {
            if (favorites.size() ==0){
                Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MyFavoriteActivity.this);
                dialog.setTitle(R.string.no_favorites_items);
                dialog.show();
            }

            ListView favList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.FavoriteLayoutListView);

            if(favorites != null){
                favouritesAdapter = new FavouritesAdapter(MyFavoriteActivity.this, favorites);
                favList.setAdapter(favouritesAdapter);

                favList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1,
                                            int position, long arg3) {

                    }
                });





                favList.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                                   int position, long id) {

                        ImageView button = (ImageView) view
                                .findViewById(R.id.list_fav_icon);

                        String tag = button.getTag().toString();
                        if (tag.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
                            sharedPreference.addFavorite(MyFavoriteActivity.this,
                                    favorites.get(position));
                            Toast.makeText(
                                    MyFavoriteActivity.this,
                                    R.string.add_favr,
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            button.setTag("yes");
                            button.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_active);
                        } else {
                            sharedPreference.removeFavorite(MyFavoriteActivity.this,
                                    favorites.get(position));
                            button.setTag("no");
                            button.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_default);
                            Toast.makeText(
                                    MyFavoriteActivity.this,
                                    R.string.remove_favr,
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

}
```

This is FavoriteListAdapter.java.class

```
public class FavouritesAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    //Variables
    Context mContext;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    List<Model> modellist;
    ArrayList<Model> arrayList;
    private Model model;

    //Constructor
    public FavouritesAdapter(Context context, List<Model> modellist) {
        mContext = context;
        this.modellist = modellist;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        this.arrayList = new ArrayList<Model>();
        this.arrayList.addAll(modellist);

    }

    public class ViewHolder{
        TextView mTitleTv, mDescTv;
        ImageView mIconTv, favIcon;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return modellist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return modellist.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (view==null){
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);

            //locate the views in row.xml
            holder.mTitleTv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mainTitle);
            holder.mDescTv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mainDesc);
            holder.mIconTv = view.findViewById(R.id.mainIcon);

            view.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
        }

        //set the result into textview
        holder.mTitleTv.setText(modellist.get(i).getTitle());
        holder.mDescTv.setText(modellist.get(i).getDesc());
        //Set the result in imagview
        holder.mIconTv.setImageResource(modellist.get(i).getIcon());

        //listview item clicks
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //code later
                if (modellist.get(i).getTitle().equals("This is the lyrics content example of the song1")){
                    //start NewActivity with title for actionbar and text for textview
                    Intent intent =  new Intent(mContext, NewActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("actionBarTitle", "Song 001");
                    intent.putExtra("contentTv", "This is the lyrics content example of the song2");
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                }
                if (modellist.get(i).getTitle().equals("This is the lyrics content example of the song1")){
                    //start NewActivity with title for actionbar and text for textview
                    Intent intent =  new Intent(mContext, NewActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("actionBarTitle", "Song 002");
                    intent.putExtra("contentTv", "This is the lyrics content example of the song2");
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                }
                if (modellist.get(i).getTitle().equals("This is the lyrics content example of the song3")){
                    //start NewActivity with title for actionbar and text for textview
                    Intent intent =  new Intent(mContext, NewActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("actionBarTitle", "Song 003");
                    intent.putExtra("contentTv", "This is the lyrics content example of the song3");
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                }
                if (modellist.get(i).getTitle().equals("This is the lyrics content example of the song4")){
                    //start NewActivity with title for actionbar and text for textview
                    Intent intent =  new Intent(mContext, NewActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("actionBarTitle", "Song 004");
                    intent.putExtra("contentTv", "This is the lyrics content example of the song4");
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                }
                if (modellist.get(i).getTitle().equals("This is the lyrics content example of the song5")){
                    //start NewActivity with title for actionbar and text for textview
                    Intent intent =  new Intent(mContext, NewActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("actionBarTitle", "Song 005");
                    intent.putExtra("contentTv", "This is the lyrics content example of the song5");
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                }

            }
        });


        return view;
    }

    //filter
    public void filter(String charText){
        charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        modellist.clear();
        if (charText.length()==0){
            modellist.addAll(arrayList);
        }
        else {
            for (Model model : arrayList){
                if (model.getTitle().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText)){
                    modellist.add(model);
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

This is the LogCat

```
    --------- beginning of crash
2019-10-22 02:02:39.715 11214-11214/com.gritchen.redeemedsongs E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.gritchen.redeemedsongs, PID: 11214
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.ArrayList com.gritchen.redeemedsongs.SharedPreference.getFavorites(android.content.Context)' on a null object reference
        at com.gritchen.redeemedsongs.ListViewAdapter.checkFavoriteItem(ListViewAdapter.java:372)
        at com.gritchen.redeemedsongs.ListViewAdapter.getView(ListViewAdapter.java:86)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2365)
        at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:2052)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:786)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:847)
        at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1826)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2164)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20323)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6199)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1083)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20323)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6199)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20323)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6199)
        at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:443)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20323)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6199)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20323)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6199)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1791)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1635)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1544)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20323)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6199)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:764)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20323)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6199)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2612)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2317)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1453)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7047)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:924)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:732)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:664)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:910)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6524)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:888)
2019-10-22 02:02:39.737 11214-11253/com.gritchen.redeemedsongs D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2019-10-22 02:02:39.899 11214-11253/com.gritchen.redeemedsongs D/libc-netbsd: getaddrinfo: get result from proxy gai_error = 0
2019-10-22 02:02:39.918 11214-11253/com.gritchen.redeemedsongs I/System.out: port:443
2019-10-22 02:02:41.595 11214-11239/com.gritchen.redeemedsongs
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling

```
List<Model> favorites = sharedPreference.getFavorites(mContext);
```

Where sharedPreference is never instanciated. Thus throwing a NullPointerException. Try instanciating the object in your constructor

```
//Constructor
    public ListViewAdapter(Context context, List<Model> modellist) {
        mContext = context;
        this.modellist = modellist;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        this.arrayList = new ArrayList<Model>();
        this.arrayList.addAll(modellist);
        this.sharedPreference = new SharedPreference();
}
```

Comment: Yes you are very correct. I forgot to instantiate the SharedPreference. Thanks

Comment: I have a new problem. The listView items are scattered and i can't figure out what the problem is. Could you please help me with your email so that i can attach the full project code for you to help me fix. Please i want to zip the project and send to you to help me fix. Thanks